# How can I use drupal_add_js() to include the following script?

Tags: javascript

How can I use `drupal_add_js()` to include the following script?

```
<script src="http://example.net/script.js" data-config="{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'','url':'https://soundcloud.com/fosterthepeoplemusic/pumpedupkicks'}]}" ></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this issue and was able to work around the limitations of `drupal_add_js()` with the following hack:

```
//this can be any string of js that's already wrapped in <script> elements
$my_script = '<script ...[all the things]... ></script>';

drupal_add_js('</script>' . $my_script . '<script>', array(
  'type' => 'inline',
  'scope' => 'header', //or 'footer'
  //...any other options you want to add
));
```

You end up with two empty `<script>` elements in your markup, which I find annoying, but they don't actually do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with [drupal_add_html_head](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) like below:

```
$data_config = "{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'','url':'https://soundcloud.com/fosterthepeoplemusic/pumpedupkicks'}]}";
$my_script = array(
    '#tag' => 'script',
    '#attributes' => array(
        'src' => 'http://example.net/script.js',
        'type' => 'text/javascript',
        'data-config' => $data_config,
    )
);
drupal_add_html_head($my_script, 'mymodule');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code put the js after head tag. but how can insert it right under <body> or <body>

Comment: is it possible to use just drupal_add_js() instead of drupal_add_html_head?

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot use drupal_add_js(). See https://www.drupal.org/node/1664602

Comment: Also drupal_add_html_head() adds output to the HEAD tag of the HTML page. We cannot make it insert in the <body> tag. You would have to do that manually somewhere in the page using a template. i.e. if you REALLY need this in the <body>.

Answer (score 0):

AdvAgg can do it as it supports the attributes key.

```
drupal_add_js("http://example.net/script.js", array(
  'attributes' => array(
    'data-config' => "{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'','url':'https://soundcloud.com/fosterthepeoplemusic/pumpedupkicks'}]}",
  ),
));
```

If you want to target a specific location for the js, advagg also allows for this; on "admin/config/development/performance/advagg" check the "Allow for JS to be added to blocks and views" button at the bottom.

```
drupal_add_js("http://example.net/script.js", array(
  'scope' => 'page_top:prefix',
  'attributes' => array(
    'data-config' => "{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'','url':'https://soundcloud.com/fosterthepeoplemusic/pumpedupkicks'}]}",
  ),
));
```

Set `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` in your settings.php file to see all possible scopes; simply look for `<!-- AdvAgg page_top:prefix tag -->` in the page source code and know the JS will land there.